# React Native Error(Not warning) : VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews with the same orientation - use another one

Tags: react-native

I used the following code structure.

```
render() {
    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center" }}>
            <ScrollView>
                <FlatList horizontal="true" />
                <FlatList horizontal="true" />
                <FlatList horizontal="true" />
                <FlatList horizontal="true" />
                <FlatList horizontal="true" />
                <FlatList horizontal="true" />
            </ScrollView>
        </View>
    );
}
```

Then I got this error.
VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews with the same orientation - use another VirtualizedList-backed container instead. How to solve it?

Comment: What's the purpose of your `ScrollView` ? ...

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The purpose of ScrollView is to scroll page vertically.
There are 6 horizontal FlatList that can't make in a loop. So making 6 FlatLists are inevitable.